# Can't open image inside org file: openwith-file-handler

Tags: org-mode, images

Linux Mint 19.3

Emacs 26.1

In my org file:

```
* TODO Test insert image
  Test this
  #+CAPTION: This is the caption for the next figure link (or table)
  #+NAME:   Deepspace
  [[./KLOCKA6.JPG]]
    
* TODO Hello from this 
  Hello
```

Org file and  `KLOCKA6.JPG` are in the same folder.

I want to show image inside org file. So I use command:

```
org-toggle-inline-images
```

But I get message:

```
openwith-file-handler: Opened KLOCKA6.JPG in external program
```

In my init.el file:

```
(when (require 'openwith nil 'noerror)
  (setq openwith-associations
        (list 
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("doc" "docx" "rtf")) "word" '(file))
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("mpg" "mpeg" "mp3" "mp4" "avi" "wmv" "wav" "mov" "mkv")) "vlc" '(file))
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("pdf")) "FoxitReader" '(file))
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("bmp" "gif" "jpeg" "jpg" "png" "tif")) "xnview" '(file))
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("rdp")) "Remote Desctop Connection" '(file))
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("xls" "xlsx")) "excel" '(file))
         ))
  (openwith-mode 1))
```

Comment: In yr config, you have activated `openwith`.  Turn that off and try again.

Comment: @FranBurstall after I turn off "openwith" in my init.el  - now it's work. Success show image inside org file. Nice... but the problem is ... I want to see image inside in org AND open image by "openWith" in dired mode. Is it possible?

Comment: OP: please add such additional qualification to your question. Comments can be deleted at any time. If there were existing answers posted I'd instead request that you pose a separate question - it's not fair to move the goal post, i.e., change the question. But in this case there are no answers yet, so please consider editing the question to make it more precise (e.g. Dired etc.). Thx.